# How to change Texture in material of special Shader by Unity Script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Goal**

I imported a special shader graph that I use in a material. I have a GameObject with  Component.

At runtime when user click on a simple button I want to change my GameObject > Mesh Renderer > Material > Speical Shader > Texture with my new textures.

**Content**

I use Built-in and Unity 2021.3.11f1. I am using special shader.
[Shader Graph Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7LFX.png)

I want to change skin texture by unity script.

Tests I made texture change script but it has some issues.

**Code**

```
public Texture2D[] MyTexture;

public Material DefaultMat;

public void ChangeSkin(int index) 
{
   DefaultMat.Skin = MyTexture[index];
}
```

Comment: This is not `unityscript`, this is `c#`. `unityscript` was discontinued years ago. I will update the tags for you, but please for your next question, just use the text `c#` and `unity-game-engine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you usually do this:
`DefaultMat.SetTexture("_MainTex", MyTexture);`
If your custom shader has a different name for the texture, replace that with the default "_MainTex" string.

Here is the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTexture.html

Comment: I used this command but I have to select mesh render if use command.
Can I change material texture not from mesh renderer?